# Windows10 WSL2 "gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed"

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install docker in Windows 10 (WSL2 - Ubuntu 20.04LTS) and run the following command, it's not working, the console displays this message "gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed"

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to the agent: IPC connect call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463220/how-to-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call)

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that your Ubuntu 20.04 is using WSL 2. When I installed it is was set to WSL1. Changing it to WSL2 seemed to have done the trick.

In Powershell run this command:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
```

Comment: When I tried the wsl command above, I got this message in ps: `There is no distribution with the supplied name.` Yet I previously confirmed inside my ubuntu shell that it's version 20.04. What am I missing?

Comment: Mine also had a different name. Use `wsl --list` to show your distributions, then replace the `Ubuntu-20.04` part of the above command with the correct name for your local Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have WSL 2, you'll need to install Ubuntu 18.04 from the Windows store.

I just ran into the same issue with a fresh WSL + Docker install. As is documented in [issue #5125](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5125) in the WSL repo, **Ubuntu 20.04 is incompatible with WSL 1**. After installing Ubuntu 18.04, I was able to work through the rest of the [Docker install instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and continue through [this useful tutorial](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly).